# How to combine two or more Docker images

Tags: docker

I'm a newbie to docker.
I want to create an image with my web application. I need some application server, e.g. wlp, then I need some database, e.g. postgres.

There is a Docker image for wlp and there is a Docker image for postgres.

So I created following simple Dockerfile.

```
FROM websphere-liberty:javaee7
FROM postgres:latest
```

Now, maybe it's a lame, but when I build this image

```
docker build -t wlp-db .
```

run container

```
docker run -it --name wlp-db-test wlp-db
```

and check it

```
docker exec -it wlp-db-test /bin/bash
```

only postgres is running and wlp is not even there. Directory **/opt** is empty.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please remove the java tag, possibly also the others. This is a pure docker question.

Comment: I suggest you go to the Docker Compose Quickstart site

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use docker-compose file. This makes you bind two different containers that are running two different images. One holding your server and the other the database services.

Here is the Example of a nodejs server container working with a mongodb container

**First of All, i write the docker file to configure the main container**

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir /src

RUN npm install nodemon -g

WORKDIR /src
ADD app/package.json package.json
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm start
```

**Then i Create the docker-compose file to configure both containers and link them**

```
version: '3' #docker-compose version
services:  #Services are your different containers
  node_server: #First Container, containing nodejs serveer
    build: . #Saying that all of my source files are at the root path
    volumes: #volume are for hot reload for exemple
      - "./app:/src/app"
    ports:   #binding the host port with the machine
      - "3030:3000"
    links:   #Linking the first service with the named mongo service (see below)
      - "mongo:mongo" 
  mongo: #declaration of the mongodb container
    image: mongo #using mongo image
    ports:  #port binding for mongodb is required
      - "27017:27017"
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: Docker uses # as comments

Comment: Any database scripts to create databases, tables etc. should be passed into containter and run in it using dockerfile?

Comment: scripts are in your server code. You do one DockerFile in your project. And one docker-compose.yml.

Comment: This is serious one of the most helpful answer I've found related to docker multi images.

Answer (score 4):

Each service should have its own image/dockerfile. You start multiple containers and connect them over a network to be able to communicate.
If you wish to compose multiple containers in one file, check out `docker-compose`, which is made for just that!

Answer (score 3):

You can't FROM multiple times in one file and expect both processes to run

That's creating each layer from the images, but only one entry point for the process, which is Postgres, because it's second

This pattern is typically only done when you have some "setup" docker image, then a "runtime" image on top of it.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds

Also what you're trying to do is not very adherent to "microservices". Run the database separately from your application. Docker Compose can assist you with that, and almost all the examples on dockers website use Postgres with some web app

Plus, you're starting an empty database and server. You need to copy at least a WAR, for example, to run your server code

Comment: "This pattern is typically only done when you have some "setup" docker image, then a "runtime" image on top of it"... Can you post some simple real-world example, please?

Comment: I did. It's called a multi stage build