# Create a container the uses files from another container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm pretty new to `docker` and currently looking for a good way to create a stateful docker image. I have a repository with configuration and DDL schema that is used by `MySQL` database. Different project depending on this configuration use different versions of the MySQL itself.

So I need to combine 2 images in one container. The first one contains just a single configuration file as follows:

```
FROM scratch
COPY db.ddl /etc/db/
```

and the second one is [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

Is it possible to do this with docker? Some workarounds?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283990/how-to-combine-two-or-more-docker-images

Comment: You should be able to use the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` mechanism to either bind-mount your schema initialization into the container, or to `COPY` that file into an image `FROM mysql`.

Comment: @DavidMaze actually I was looking for multistage build (Did not know about it before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that I was looking for is called [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) (using multiple FROM to produce the resulting image). Here is how it looks like in my case (simplified):

DDL `Dockerfile` (built as `ddlimg` image):

```
FROM scratch
COPY db.ddl /etc/db/db.ddl
```

Resulting `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ddlimg

FROM postgres    
COPY --from=ddlimg /etc/db/db.ddl /db.ddl
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```